# how to rewrite checkout cart url in magento

Tags: magento, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite my checkout/cart url to checkout/cartnew . I have tried it using config.xml but not succeded.
my code is :-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <rewrite>
            <mynamespace_mymodule_checkout_cart>
                <from>
                    <![CDATA[ #^/checkout/cart# ]]>
                </from>
                    <to>/checkout/cartnew</to>
            </mynamespace_mymodule_checkout_cart>
        </rewrite>
    </global>
</config>
```

Please suggest me how can I do this ?